# how to get instance in singleton class to check if database is already booted by a JVM

Tags: java, jvm, singleton, instance, derby

I have an application with java derby database (Embedded). As you know can't use embedded java derby database for multiple JVM connection, but I need to put my application in a shared folder for multiple users. so, for checking database is already booted by another jvm, I want to check instance. if already booted, don't allow to open application with a Message.
How can handle it in below class?

```
import org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class PersistenceManager {

    public static final boolean DEBUG = true;
    private static final PersistenceManager singleton = new PersistenceManager();
    protected EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public static PersistenceManager getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }

    private PersistenceManager() {
    }

    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        if (emf == null)
            createEntityManagerFactory();
        return emf;
    }

    public void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        if (emf != null) {
            emf.close();
            emf = null;
            if (DEBUG)
                System.out.println("n*** Persistence finished at " + new java.util.Date());
        }
    }

    protected void createEntityManagerFactory() {

            this.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit");
            if (DEBUG)
                System.out.println("n*** Persistence started at " + new java.util.Date());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to use this code in first GUI Form (LoginForm) before call EntityManagerFactory. this worked for me and dont need to change Singlton class (PersistenceManager) :

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:Mydata")) {

            LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
            loginForm.setContentPane(loginForm.panel);
            loginForm.pack();
            loginForm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            loginForm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            loginForm.setVisible(true);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if (e.getNextException().getErrorCode() == 45000){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Another user is using application");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is my answer

Comment: Did you think about what happens when another user is starting the application right after this connection has been closed but before your `PersistenceManager` opens its connection?